# Specify separate skip limits for reader, processor and writer in Spring Batch 2.1.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

How do I specify separate skip limits for reader, processor and writer in Spring Batch 2.1.x?

At present I have

```
<chunk reader="Reader" writer="Writer" processor="Processor" commit-interval="100" skip-limit="1000" />
```

However, I need the job to fail at different limits for each step.
Example: 1000 at Reader, 10 at processor and Writer.

The value is high at reader since I am reading from remote endpoint and can have read/ connect time-outs/ 404/ etc for the resource. However, once the file is read the threshold for processor and writer needs to be low.

Any pointer to configure in xml is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

skipt-limit value is a combined value for read+process+write exceptions. Its not possible to mention the skip-limit individually for read/process/writes.